# reflect same selected data in all cards of *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular-ngfor

I have created multiple cards using *ngIf. 
Inside it I have dropdown select(used mat-select). When I select one option from dropdown, selected option gets reflected to all cards which is not required.

```
<div class="allCards">
    <div *ngFor="let card of cardArray; let i=index">
      <mat-card class="example-card">
        <mat-card-header>
          <p class="productOffer">20% OFF</p>
        </mat-card-header>

          <img  mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg"
            alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
            <mat-card-subtitle>{{card.name}}</mat-card-subtitle>
        <mat-card-content>

            <del >₹{{card.orgAmt}}</del>
            <p ngDefaultControl >₹{{card.discAmt}} </p>
        </mat-card-content>


        <mat-card-actions>

          <div class="actionItems">
            <mat-form-field style="width:150px;">
              <mat-select  placeholder="Select Quantity"  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
                <mat-option ngDefaultControl  *ngFor="let food of card.foods"  [value]="food.value">
                  {{food.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>

            <span class="add-to-cart">
              <button  mat-mini-fab color="primary" (click)="decrCntr(i)" >-</button>
              <span ngDefaultControl >{{card.counterVar}}</span>
              <button  mat-mini-fab color="secondary" (click)="incrCntr(i)" >+</button>
            </span>
          </div>
          <button mat-button type='submit'(click)="onSubmit(i, selectedValue )">Add to Cart</button>

        </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you are using the same variable `selectedValue` everywhere. might want to check that. once set, its value is being reflected elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

at **[(ngModel)]="selectedValue"** add the index value so that it will be unique

**[(ngModel)]="selectedValue{{i}}"**

Comment: could work, `selectedValue` must be `any` or an `array`. else he would get `selectedValueN` is not defined/undefined error.

Comment: selectedValue should be a array

Comment: got error : <br/> Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 13 in [selectedValue{{i}}]

Comment: can u please share your code snippet @PravinPokharkar

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have same `[(ngModel)]="selectedValue"` for all select. You can try to make like this :
`[(ngModel)]="selectedValue{{i}}"`

Comment: check my comment on @Santhosh's answer. this could give him more errors.

Comment: Need to look error or give me example on StackBlitz or some screenshots

Comment: got error : <br/> Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 13 in [selectedValue{{i}}]

Comment: @ Pravin Pokharkar try use [(ngModel)]=" `${selectedValue}${i}` "